Bootstrapping Methods for Logistic Regression Models
I have a continuous numeric predictor variable and a continuous numeric response variable (the response variable is bounded by 0 and 1, and there are 0s and 1s in the response column, but the predictor variable is not bounded at all). I have these data for several species of plants and for 3 (and occasionally fewer than 3) individuals of each species, and I have hundreds of observations for each individual.
My goal is to fit logistic models to these data by species. I plan to fit a logistic model on each individual and then use the parameters (slopes and intercepts) from these individual models to generate species models by calculating the mean slopes and intercepts across individuals within species.
To generate confidence intervals about the models, I plan on bootstrapping. Instead of sampling (with replacement) from the 3 slopes and intercepts of each species - 3 seems like not a lot of replicates - I plan on assuming that slopes and intercepts within a species are normally distributed and randomly estimating slopes and intercepts from these distributions.
Does this method sound reasonable, and if it doesn't, what are some good alternatives?
This question is a follow-up question from this one - my original question was about if I should use parameter (slope and intercept) standard deviations or standard errors when I perform the bootstrapping (in other words, if standard deviations or standard errors should be used as the standard deviations of the normal distributions I'm assuming these parameters come from).

My first impulse would be a generalized mixed effects model: the "generalized" part would be a binomial distribution family, the "mixed effects" part would allow putting all your data into a single model with random effects per individual or species (the nesting would indicate that a hierarchical approach would be useful). Typically, one tries to put everything into a single big well-specified model, rather than fitting separate models to subsets of the data and then combining the models.

Thank you for this outstanding answer, but I need to modify my question since I don't actually have binary response data - I have a continuous numeric response variable that is bounded by 0 and 1! I still want to perform logistic regression. Can I still use lme4::glmer()?

Technically it wouldn't be called "logistic regression" any more. It would probably be Beta regression; if your responses include values that are exactly 0 or exactly 1 (or both), then things get trickier (zero-one inflated Beta reg, ordered beta reg, 'squashing' ... there's probably a CV question about this already): https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=beta+regression+zero
